# xhprof walltime always 0 microseconds

Tags: php, profiling, xhprof

Installed xhprof and everything is working fine, except that the wall-time is always 0 microseconds. This is what the summary reports:

```
Total Incl. Wall Time (microsec):   0 microsecs
Total Incl. CPU (microsecs):    1,078,125 microsecs
Total Incl. MemUse (bytes): 9,343,272 bytes
Total Incl. PeakMemUse (bytes): 9,400,384 bytes
Number of Function Calls:   54,835
```

I have googled myself senseless, but to no avail. Has anyone experienced this him/herself and more important: what can be done about this?

Configuration: XAMPP 3.1.0, PHP 5.4, Apache 2.4.3